# DATALENGTH VARCHAR in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

According to MSDN the storage size of a VARCHAR data type is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes. I'm trying to understand why when I run this query:

```
DECLARE @VARCHAR VARCHAR(40) = 'RACING CLUB DE AVELLANEDA'
SELECT DATALENGTH(@VARCHAR) AS Bytes, LEN(@VARCHAR) AS Characters;
```

The storage size of @VARCHAR is the same as it was a CHAR data type, It's 25 and not 27 (25+2).

Does it has something to do with DATALENGTH function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

datalength will tell you the number of bytes of data, which doesn't include the 2 bytes that precede that data in storage. The 2 byte overhead of a varchar is for recording the number of bytes in the string - i.e. in your case 25

Comment: I see. Is there a function or sp to get the number of bytes in storage it needs?

Comment: `DATALENGTH(@VARCHAR)+2`  :)

Answer (score 4):

`DATALENGTH` returns the number of `bytes used`

`LEN` returns the number of `characters used`

Just compare these results

```
DECLARE @VARCHAR VARCHAR(40) = 'RACING CLUB DE AVELLANEDA'
SELECT DATALENGTH(@VARCHAR) AS Bytes, LEN(@VARCHAR) AS Characters;

Bytes: 25 ==> As it is a variable length, returns 25    
Characters: 25
```

---

```
DECLARE @VARCHAR CHAR(40) = 'RACING CLUB DE AVELLANEDA'
SELECT DATALENGTH(@VARCHAR) AS Bytes, LEN(@VARCHAR) AS Characters;

Bytes: 40 ==> As it is a fixed length, returns 40
Characters: 25
```

---

```
DECLARE @VARCHAR NVARCHAR(40) = 'RACING CLUB DE AVELLANEDA'
SELECT DATALENGTH(@VARCHAR) AS Bytes, LEN(@VARCHAR) AS Characters;

Bytes: 50 ==> As it is a variable length, returns 25*2 = 50
Characters: 25
```

---

```
DECLARE @VARCHAR NCHAR(40) = 'RACING CLUB DE AVELLANEDA'
SELECT DATALENGTH(@VARCHAR) AS Bytes, LEN(@VARCHAR) AS Characters;

Bytes: 80 ==> As it is a fixed length, returns 40*2 = 80
Characters: 25
```

Also you can easily add `+2` to your `DATALENGTH` for `VARCHAR` data types

```
DECLARE @VARCHAR VARCHAR(40) = 'RACING CLUB DE AVELLANEDA'
SELECT  DATALENGTH(@VARCHAR) AS Bytes
        ,LEN(@VARCHAR) AS Characters
        ,DATALENGTH(@VARCHAR) + 2 AS ActualUsedBytes
```

Output

```
Bytes   Characters  ActualUsedBytes
25      25          27
```